# AngularJS not sending data via POST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to save to JSON some form data via AngularJS $http.post but somehow it isn't working. The idea is pretty simple: I have a form with three fields, an AngularJS data-binding and a pretty simple PHP code to save it to a file. Somehow it isn't working because the PHP file doesn't get any input apparently, so it always stores `null`.

Here is the code:

HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="book.title" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pages" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pages:</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="pages" ng-model="book.pages" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="readPages" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Read pages:</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="readPages" ng-model="book.readPages" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" ng-click="save()"></button>
</form>
```

The JS code:

```
angular.module('book', [
    'ui.router'
])
    .config(function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('book', {
            url: '/book',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'Book',
                    templateUrl: 'ui/views/book.tpl.html'
                },
                "header": {
                    templateUrl: 'ui/views/header.tpl.html'
                },
                "footer": {
                    templateUrl: 'ui/views/footer.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data: {pageTitle: 'Book Status'}
        });
    })

    .controller('Book',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.book = {};
        $scope.error = "";

        $scope.save = function() {
            console.log($scope.book);
            $http.post('save/book.php', $scope.book).then(function(response) {
                // log success
                console.log("Guardado con éxito.");
                console.log(response);
              });
        };
});
```

And the PHP code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$inp = file_get_contents('../data/books.json');

$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
$tempData = json_decode($data);
array_push($tempArray, $tempData);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
$file = fopen('../data/books.json','w+');
fwrite($file, $jsonData);
fclose($file);
echo $jsonData;
```

So, apparently everything is correct, but I'm getting this response:

> ( ! ) Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null
>   given in C:\wamp\www\angulardemos\save\book.php on line 7

Which tells me that the input is incorrect, so I'm not actually sending any data. What am I missing?

Comment: easy `$tempArray` is null add var_dump

Comment: Yes, I know that $tempArray is null, the var_dump shows `null`, but it shouldn't.

Comment: pass true `$tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);`

Comment: Since it is saying parameter 1 is null it should be an array. It means there is a problem with this $inp = file_get_contents('../data/books.json'); you are not getting data from 'books.json'.

There is nothing wrong with angular part.

Comment: I second that. The angular part seems ok, you can verify this by catching your request and confirming there is actual data being transferred. This would imply your php code is erroneous somewhere. I suspect the same as @NeerajVerma

Comment: I found the problem, and it was dumbest than I could think: the `books.json` file was empty and I didn't checked that, so when I use it as an array is obviously null and I should have initialized it. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

easy `$tempArray` is null add var_dump to debug it

```
$tempArray = $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
$tempData = json_decode($data);
array_push($tempArray, $tempData);
```

You can also try:

```
$tempArray[]=$tempData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove book from ng-model and make it to 
   `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Title">`

likewise for all.. and in the save function 
`var dataObj = {
                            title: $scope.title,
                            pages: $scope.pages

                        }`
`var res =  $http.post('save/book.php', JSON.stringify(dataObj)`